# The present simple vs present continuous in context

Tags: grammar, present-continuous, present-simple

Let's say there is a treadmill  that broke down. And a person asks me if he can use it. What sentence would be the most appropriate to answer the question.

> Sorry, It doesn't work.
>
> Sorry, it is not working.

I would say the second option is a better choice, because it is out of commission temporarily and it is going to be fixed soon. Tell me please if my thinking is correct.

Comment: I would just say *it's broken*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is right. "It doesn't work" is what you might say if the treadmill hasn't worked in years, or about something you've never seen to work correctly at all. "It's not working" is what you say about something that usually works, but for some reason has temporarily stopped.

This is of course a matter of perspective, so two different people with different levels of familiarity with the treadmill in question (or different levels of trust in the person who told them it was to be fixed soon) might talk about it differently.